# Rails 4: Cache digest doesn't change cache_key when I update view

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm likely doing something silly, missing a step, or something, but I can't seem to make digest caching work the way I believe it should.

My understanding is that, in rails 4, doing this:

```
- cache ['v1',@article] do
  = render :partial => "show_article", :locals => { :article => @article}
```

Should build a cache digest that includes an MD5 of the view. And I see something like that in my logs:

```
Write fragment views/v1/articles/198-20130904195924000000000/2c68729b145522780d64dee67957c0e3
```

But, if I later change show_article.haml:

```
%h2 This should change the view's MD5.
```

Then reload the same page, I get:

```
Read fragment views/v1/articles/198-20130904195924000000000/2c68729b145522780d64dee67957c0e3
```

instead of a fresh render. Isn't the whole idea of digest caching that I DON'T have to update the "v1" string every time I edit a view file?

Or am I misunderstanding this?

This is made all the more difficult because in Rails 3 I could do this when using the cache_digests gem:

```
rake cache_digests:nested_dependencies TEMPLATE=articles/show
```

But that rake task doesn't exist in rails 4, even though the cache_digests gem is now part of it.

Comment: Do you have `config.action_view.cache_template_loading` enabled by any chance?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  If I restart the server (POW) and request the page, it then picks up the new MD5 for the modified file. It doesn't seem to matter what we set cache_template_loading set to.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Rails from **4.0.0** to **4.0.2** and the cache digest appears to be working correctly!